# How to create a stable swapping pool between and BEP-20 token and BUSD

Tags: solidity, uniswap, pancakeswap

i am working on a task in which i need to swap a BEP-20 token with BUSD. while swapping of after swapping their price should remain stable up 1 dollar , with min slippage. on which platform did i need to create a liquidity pool , or is it necessary to pagged the BEP-20 token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want it to stay pegged to 1 BUSD, you can create your own smart contract that sends back 1 token BEP20 if it get 1 BUSD, or the reverse.
So your contract act as an arbitrage tool to keep the peg.

Or you can create a 'uniswap pool' with your BEP-20/BUSD, but it will require a lot of liquidity or an arbitrage system to keep the peg.

For exemple: https://v2.info.uniswap.org/pair/0x3041cbd36888becc7bbcbc0045e3b1f144466f5f

The uniswap pair USDC - USDT has 10 millions in it, and if one token is exchanged more and the pool start to be unbalanced, the miner or MEV extractors will see it as an arbitrage opportunity and will make some money rebalancing the pool.

Hope this helps, but please ask follow up questions if I wasn't clear enough

Comment: well fist method seems more easy to implement than the second. will you please tell me little bit more about 1st method , how to build arbitrage in the contract.

Comment: A smart contract that sends back 1 token when a user sends 1 BUSD to it. A user would have to call the approve function of the busd contract and approve your smart contract, then call the mint function of your smart contract. The mint function will call BUSD.transferFrom(user, address(this), amountToMint) which will transfer the busd from the user to the contract, and then mint new tokens and send them to the user "balances[msg.sender] += amountToMint". You will have to have a withdraw function where user can send the tokens to, tokens will be burned and the busd transfer back to the user